# Postgres: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insufficient data left in message

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I read enough to know that this occurs when a string contains some characters that Postgres doesn't like. However, I cannot figure out if there is a way to validate strings before writing them. In particular, I'm doing batch inserts.

```
insert into foo(col1,col2,col3) values ('a',2,3),('b',4,0),....
```

My DB is setup like this:

```
   Name     | Owner  | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges
------------+--------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 stats      | me     | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

Periodically, some bad string will get in and the whole insert will fail(e.g. `changeï¿½ï¿½ï¿½=`). I batch up quite a few values in a single insert so I'd like to ideally validate the string rather than bomb the whole insert. Is there a list of which characters are not allowed in a Postgres insert?

Using postgresql-jdbc 9.1-901.jdbc4

Comment: I fixed the insert statement -- I have no doubts about the insert statement itself, it worked fine until some naughty strings made it in

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: After reading other SO posts and looking at the string, I noticed that I had some NULL characters in there so I ended up filtering out all control characters (e.g. str.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");). I still don't know of official documentation of what UTF ranges are not allowed but this seemingly solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message means that your string data has a null character `"\0"` in it.

I can't find an authoritative cite for this (let me know if you have one).

- It is discussed at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/alpine.BSO.2.00.0906031639270.2432%40leary.csoft.net
- It is mentioned in passing in the official docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html

All other characters are allowed.

Comment: I was running a bunch ofn update queries using npgsql from .net. The source of the strings was some text I scraped from the web and I was getting this error. My solution was to strip the non-ascii characters (including \0 which is technically an ascii char) using regex: Regex.Replace(sql.ToString, "[^\u0001-\u007F]+", String.Empty)

Comment: @BradMathews This suggestion saved us! We are migrating from mongo do a relational database and one of the entities had hundreds of fields. A bunch of them happen to be to do with web data so I honed in on those ones and found the culprit! Still going to be a separate challenge to migrate those but at least the bulk of the entity can be migrated.

Answer (score 8):

date type is not match target type.for example int4->int8

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I was loading query from an sql file. The problem was due to the encoding.
I change it to UTF-8 and it works. Hope that helps !