# libpq ERROR: insufficient data left in message

Tags: postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

I am using libpq to interact with PostgreSQL DB. I'm getting below error while trying to update the table.

> ERROR:  insufficient data left in message

I have created a sample code with same parameters and it also is giving me the same error
Below is the sample code

```
    std::string sQuery("update client_backlog_period set starttime = $1, endtime = $2, unavailable = $3 where periodid = $4");

    int nElem = 4;
    
    timestamp start_time = 736260060000000, end_time = 736260900000000;
    short nUnavailable = 0;
    long nPeriodid = 1;

    start_time = boost::endian::native_to_big(start_time);
    end_time = boost::endian::native_to_big(end_time);
    nUnavailable = boost::endian::native_to_big(nUnavailable);
    nPeriodid = boost::endian::native_to_big(nPeriodid);

    const char* paramValues[4] = { (char*)&start_time, (char*)&end_time, (char*)&nUnavailable, (char*)&nPeriodid};
    Oid paramTypes[4] = { TIMESTAMPOID, TIMESTAMPOID, INT2OID , INT8OID };

    int paramLengths[4] = { sizeof(start_time), sizeof(end_time),sizeof(nUnavailable), sizeof(nPeriodid) };
    int paramFormats[4] = { 1,1,1,1 };
    PGresult* res = PQexecParams(db.m_pPGConn,
            sQuery.c_str(),
            nElem,
            paramTypes,
            paramValues,
            paramLengths,
            paramFormats,
            1
        );

    ExecStatusType status = PQresultStatus(res);
    if (status != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "\n Update Query failed, Error: " << PQerrorMessage(res) << ",status: " << status << std::endl;
PQclear(res);
    }
```

> PQerrorMessage(res) is returning ERROR:  insufficient data left in message
> status is PGRES_FATAL_ERROR

The insertion and select stmt are working fine.

[image: table description]

Answer (score 0):

This might be down to a few things (referenced in the below post) I'll summarize them here.

1. There is a datatype mismatch between the value you are attempting to update and the datatype defined for those columns within the table (starttime,endtime or unavailable in your case)
2. Your data has a null character in it `"\0"`
3. An issue to do with DB encoding, change to UTF-8 and this works.

[Postgres: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insufficient data left in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308418/postgres-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-insufficient-data-left-in-me)

Comment: I have already gone through the given link. In my case both server and client has same encoding which is UTF8

Comment: Could you share your table definition for client_backlog_period. It also might be worth turning that update into an insert against a CTAS copy of that table minus any PK definition within this code just to see what is being written.

Comment: It might also by worth testing out a filter out of null characters on the assumption that there are some e.g.. `UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = replace(my_column, '\x00', '')
`

Comment: Also.. Check that your libpq library version matches the postgres server version you are connecting to. When trying the insert suggestion above try using bytea datatypes that can store null characters

Comment: The libpq version I'm using is 15.2 (I installed it from VS vcpkg) and server major version is 11. I have updated the table description as image in question only. For now I have changed the the paramFormat from 1 to 0 for all and change the paramValues accordingly and now its working. If this issue is due to mismatch b/w client and server version than I believe its better to go with text format.

Comment: Good stuff, glad it's sorted.